# How to highlight a specific `QWidget`

Tags: c++, qt, event-handling

For a searching/linking behavior, the idea is to highlight the specific `QWidget` resulting from the search.

In my first prototype, it just create on top of the given `QWidget` a decoration for the highlight. However, when the widget is resized, the highlight does not adapt/align.

```
DecorationWidget decoration;
...
QWidget* result = search(searchStr);
if (result)
{
    decoration.setParent(result);
    decoration.setGeometry(QRect(QPoint(0,0),result->size()));
    decoration.raise();
    decoration.show();

}
else
{
    decoration.hide();
}
```

**How could I detect the `QWidget` resizing?**

I obviously though about connecting, but the `QWidget` does not emit on resize. It is also not allowed to `extends` the widget because the search could point to any arbitrary `QWidget`.

Changing the style of the `QWidget` itself (actually changing anything of the QWidget) is not allowed, as it might have a specific style or `PaintEvent` implementation.

Comment: Please, have a look on [Qt: Event Filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters). This looks promising.

Comment: Thanks Scheff, yes, it seem promising.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be easily done with event filter.

In DecorationWidget override the eventFilter method (derived from QObject) and capture resize event there.

For example:

```
bool DecorationWidget::eventFilter(QObject* watched, QEvent* event)
{
    if(event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
    {
        QResizeEvent *resizeEvent = static_cast<QResizeEvent *>(event);
        resize(resizeEvent->size());
    }
    return false;
}
```

Than on the *result* widget install the instance of DecorationWidget as event filter:

```
result->installEventFilter(myDecorationWidget);
```

Remember to remove the event filter when you switch to another widget.

```
prevoiusResult->removeEventFiter(myDecorationWidget);
```

[Documentation about event filters](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.8/eventsandfilters.html#event-filters)